# How can I restrict access to collections when using Firestore's REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've noticed that when making a `GET` request to the Firestore's REST API with a Collection path, the response will be the whole collection(I didn't check with a big collection).

I would like to know how can I limit the number of retrieved documents when such request is made. For example, return only 15.

Comment: When you say "restrict access", do you mean restrict it to authenticated users or do you mean " to put some limits on the number of documents"?

Comment: Both if possible

Comment: [firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to restrict it server side

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought that it worked only on documents

Answer (score 1):

When using the [list method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list) to get documents in a collection, you can use the `pageSize` query parameter along with `pageToken` to limit the number of documents, as described in the documentation.

> **pageSize**
>
> The maximum number of documents to return.
>
> **pageToken**
>
> The nextPageToken value returned from a previous List request, if any.

Comment: It's not what I meant, I just don't want anyone to be able to get full chunks of my database, but thank you!

Comment: Then could you edit your question to describe more specifically how exactly you would like to limit or protect your data?